# Is there a public hosted CDN for Beebole's PURE?

Tags: javascript, templates, unobtrusive-javascript

i'm trying to use jsfiddle.net to try out [Pure Unobtrusive Rendering Engine](http://beebole.com/pure/)

Is there a CDN for it?

Answer (score 3):

not that I know of (yet), but you could link directly to their demo server, but only for jsFiddle testing ;-)

```
 http://beebole.com/pure/wp-content/themes/BeeBole-pure/libs/pure.js
```

UPDATE: Here's a link to their greatest and latest, thanks to @Mic!!

```
https://raw.github.com/pure/pure/master/libs/pure.js
```

Comment: we do not update every time our web site, the latest version is available from the repository at: http://github.com/pure/pure/raw/master/libs/pure.js

Comment: Now there IS a CDN - http://cdnjs.com/ Here is a direct link to PURE - //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pure/0.2.1/pure-min.css

Comment: I think that CDN is for pure.css (http://purecss.io), which is the CSS modules created by Yahoo, whereas pure.js (http://beebole.com/pure/) is a Javascript templating engine created by Beebole. I wish they had different names because I've been Googling about pure.js and it's so hard because most of the results are about pure.css since it's so popular.